# How to locate chart labels correctly?

Tags: code-request, charts

Given

```
ClearAll[a, b, c];
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 1, 6, 3, 2};
c = {0, 9, 1, 2, 8};
BarChart[Append[#, Total@#] & /@ {a, b, c}, ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None},
ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "T"}
]
```

I get:

[image]

As seen from the bar chart above, `T` denotes `Total`. The first list shows `T` as `d`, which is wrong. Secondly, the bars corresponding to `Total` should be `Black` (or any other color not used in the Bar chart) for all three lists. Most important of all, all these revisions should be made automatically when I change the length of the lists `a, b, c`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is probably to use wrapper-style `Labeled[...]` and `Style[...]` specifications as follows:

```
BarChart[
 Append[#, Labeled[Style[Total@#, Black], "T"]] & /@ {a, b, c},
 ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None},
 ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
 ]
```

[image]

Note how the style & label specified for the total bar overrides any other values, giving you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I forgot to ask about how to put a `Black` horizontal line for `Mean` value of each list rather than `Total`. Sorry, this might be another question if you think so. Now I created a `Manipulate` for two options `Total, Mean`, which works fine.